# Trying to install kubuntu from CD, but Windows10 overrides saying boot config is wrong

Tags: boot, kubuntu, windows-10

I'm trying to install kubuntu on my old laptop. I upgraded it to Win10 this summer, but wasn't happy with the result, so I've decided to give kubuntu a try. At first I tried to install it inside windows (the CD just self-launched and I went with it). During that, the installation froze, and I was forced to shutdown the computer holding the power button. After I went into BIOS and change the boot order to boot CD/DVD device first I got this message when trying to boot:

> Recovery
>
> Your PC/Device needs to be repaired
>
> The Boot Configuration Data for you PC is missing or contains errors.
>
> File: \Boot\BCD Error code: 0xc000014c
>
> You'll need to use recovery tools. If you don't have any installation
>   media (like a disc or USB device), contact your PC Administrator or
>   PC/Device manufacturer.

All with a Windows 10 layout in the background. Why does the system not allow me to boot directly from the CD? I don't care about whether Win10 likes it or not. Does anyone know how to go about this?

The CD boots on my desktop computer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem is with win10 boot mechanism. It doesn't accept Linux boot loader. You should try with new Ubuntu/Kubuntu version (made after windows 8) or install Linux on second physical drive (if you have one), then before boot you choose, which drive computer should start from (should be keyboard shortcut set in BIOS, on my computer this is F12).

If both are not possible you may try to upgrade grub, however I've never been doing this so I don't know what you should expect.